# Update parent component through dialogRef without closing the dialog

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-cli

I have a child dialog and a parent component,
My parent component have a MataTable that is updated after I click on update on my Child Dialog.

Here's the code on the parent that is working like a charm:

parentComponent.ts

```
 openDialog(e: any) {

    this.data = e;
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogAddMarqueComponent, {
      data: this.data,
      restoreFocus: false,
    });

    console.log(this.dialogRef)

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {
      if (result.length !== 0) {
        this.products.data.push(result);
        this.products = new MatTableDataSource(this.products.data);
      } else { return; }
    });
  }
```

I added a new function and button that is like the update one but without closing the DialogRef, so I want to achieve what I'm achieving inside the **dialogRef.afterClosed()** but without closing the button.

Child Component.ts

```
this.appService.addProduct(this.product)
    .subscribe(
        response => {
            this.product = response;
            this.products.data.unshift(response);
            // this.dialog.close(response); // that will trigger the dialogRef.afterclosed()

        }, error => {
            console.warn('ERROR', error);
        }
    );
```

I think i need to subscribe to the dialogRef on the parent side and as soon As I click on the Duplicate button it will update the parent.
But couldn't find what dialogRef Function to use ( I Tried Get state )
Is there a way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Dialog doesn't support change detection.

So I suggest you to achieve that this way:

1. Create a service. (`ng g s <service-name>`)
2. Put your variables in that service so you can reference them in both pages.

Now if you change the data in dialog it will change in parent page.

Answer (score 0):

The `afterClosed` event only fires after you close the modal, so you need to figure out another way to do this. For example, you can use a service that you inject in both parent and dialog component and use that to trigger the event.

The service can look like this:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class MarqueService {
  private updateSource = new Subject<Product>();

  public update$ = this.updateSource.asObservable();

  public updateProduct(product: Product): void {
    this.updateSource.next(product);
  }
}
```

You then need to inject this service in both parent component and dialog component.

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private subscription = new Subscription();

  constructor(private marqueService: MarqueService) {}
   
  ngOnInit() {
    const sub = this.marqueService.update$.subscribe((product) => {
      const products = [...this.products.data];
      const index = products.findIndex(prod => prod.id === product.id);
      products[index] = product;
      this.products.data = products;
    });
    this.subscription.add(sub);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

The dialog contains the logic to trigger the update when you click the button:

```
export class DialogAddMarqueComponent {
  constructor(private marqueService: MarqueService) {}
  // ...

  handleUpdateClick() {
    // supposing this.data is the product you are editing
    this.marqueService.updateProduct(this.data);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, Is it possible to have a working blitz please ?